# Why can't I ask a question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

**I can't ask a question on Stack Overflow**. I have not been banned. When I try to ask a question, it says:

> You must have at least **5** reputation to ask a question. Try answering some questions first.

Comment: @fsb Not a duplicate. Stack Overflow is not a beta site, and the author of this question didn't know that they were attempting to ask on a per-site meta.

Comment: You're not a new user really though, you've had a previous (deleted) account that asked several questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at [the list of privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta), it seems likely that you were trying to ask a question on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), not on [Stack Overflow proper](https://stackoverflow.com/).